# Vue router - favicon request on click a tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to Vue and am trying to build an app with Vue I used Vuerouter with history mod config but every thing until here is OK but except the menu.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li><a href="#"><i></i> parent menu <i></i></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index-2.html">submenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="dashboard-2.html">submenu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on menu link instead of open submenu I see this favico request in the network.

[image]

Comment: The favicon has nothing to do with your problem. You need to use the vue-router component like in their doc: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html